# Why doesn't Java allow the injection of nested generics?

Tags: java, generics

If I write:

```
List<List<String>> strings = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> to List<List<String>>
```

Why?

Comment: Just a guess: because there's no `new` statement for the inner nested `ArrayList`.

Comment: No, because I could write List<ArrayList<String>> strings = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(); and that is legal!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generics are not co-variant so you would have to use:

```
List<List<String>> strings = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

Notice how the outer right-hand-side declaration `ArrayList` can "become" a `List`. The same cannot be applied to anything that appears within the generics.

- [Covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29)
- [Generics Gotchas](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html)

Comment: Thanks Reimeus - I'm not familiar with covariance, can you elaborate as to what it means with regards to generics?

Comment: @TicketMonster: If you could pass `ArrayList<String>` where `List<String>` was expected then it would be covariant. I think that's one of the reasons why `? extends` and `? super` were added.

Comment: @TicketMonster: Or `List<? extends List<String>> strings = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @TicketMonster See update. This is the compilers way of protecting against dissimilar derived objects from being stored in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the code you want, you just have to update your initialization:

```
List<List<String>> strings = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

Then, for each item that you want to add to the outer list:

```
strings.add(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Comment: Yes, but why (that was my question!)?

Answer (score 0):

If this was allowed, you could end up relying on the list being a list of ArrayList at one point, while shoving something else inside elsewhere.

For instance, it would also be legal to do this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrayLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
List<List<String>> unknownLists = arrayLists ;
unknownLists.append(new LinkedList<String>());
for (ArrayList<String> l : arrayLists ) // (1)
  System.out.println(l);
```

This would compile fine, but give you a ClassCastException at (1).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because the type is insistent. However, you can write like this:

```
List<? extends List<String>> strings = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```